# Finding dates paid up to based on payments and each day costs

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet to track tutoring costs.

I want to show deposits/payments from a client, the date of these deposits being nondiscriminatory (I will sum these deposits on separate cell if necessary), and  pull information as to a date they are paid up to.

Lets say I have these four days:

```
8.09.2021   -   100$
8.16.2021   -   80$
8.23.2021   -   100$
8.30.2021   -   40$
9.06.2021   -   80$
```

The client has paid 280$ already. How can I have excel pull information that they've paid up to 8.23.2021 already. AND, if they pay the following weeks payment of 40$, how can I have it so it pulls the 8.30.2021 date...all in one formula hopefully.

I want to create a invoice, or running balance to be sent to the client on a monthly, or weekly basis.

Keep in mind that I'm creating this for my mother in-law to use, so I'm hoping I can sue excel, because she probably wont have the motivation to learn access, or any other program...AND it needs to be simple for her to use. I will lock whatever cells need to be locked, as to avoid having her input any formulas or the like

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck, exactly?

Comment: Ive tried if statements
nested if statments. 

I jsut c ant put the pieces together in order to get where i need to be

for example, i'd like it to see if, lets say theyve over paid on week, how can i calculate so that is shows how far in advance theyve paid by date?

lets say they owe 100$ a week, but one week they've paid 500$

how can i show that their next payment is due on such and such date 5 weeks away, since they've over paid. instead of next due date, maybe a "paid through date"

Comment: @David ,, if you are looking for periodic SUM then the most easiest is the Pivot Table & then **Group on Days/Months/Quarters/Years**. For weekly hit Days then below is number of dates settings, set 7. ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your sample, my sample is as following.

[image]

Please try the  formula below, it get the last payment date based on amount in E3.
`=OFFSET(A1,LOOKUP(E3-1%%%,SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B1,,,ROW($1:$100))),ROW($1:$100)+1)-1,)`

[image]

Comment: That worked swimmingly!!

Comment: That worked swimmingly!!

On another note. Can I create another cell that shows them an alert when they are past due for payment? It doesn't need to say anything ins particular, just a "Payment Due" would be fine based on the current date.  Or even better, can I show them a "Payment Due" based on todays date instead of it showing "N/A"

Comment: NVM...i think i got it

i used IFERROR, and put the offset formula in the "value" section, and then added a "Payment Due" for the "if error" section at the end

Comment: Well i basically have it...

i have it so it calculates it base on the total deposited...but not based on todays date...can you help with that?

Comment: @David - if the answer works for you, then please mark it as correct and consider upvoting it

Comment: im wondering if we can base it off of a TODAY value as well. I mean. if today they are past due, can i have it show "Payment Due"?. If they are paid up until a future date, i'd like it to show that date, but if that date passes, i'd like it to show "Payment Due"

Comment: Yes, you can use `TODAY` so see if things are past due. That said, it is better to ask a second question instead of moving the goalpost on this one. Please mark this answer as correct if it indeed works "swimmingly!".